# Hibernate 4 Data mining

Tags: java, database, hibernate, data-mining

I am developing a web application where users are allowed to view images. I wanted that site to provide related images depending on the image tags, I have heard that it is useful to use Database Mining for such cases. My question, is it possible to do Data Mining in Hibernate 4? if so how, or someone give me an overview

Answer (score 0):

Data mining is commonly used as marketing speak.

Hibernate is used to access databases using java objects, so yes it can be used for "data mining".

Your case of finding images based on tags is quite a simple algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate is meant as a transparent *persistence* layer. Well, images can easily be considered static, so no need to persist anything here.

Of course you can load your input data from Hibernate, just as you can load it directly from a database, or from a flat text file, or from an arbitrary binary file.

However, note that most data mining algorithms are quite **cpu and data intensive**. Hibernate does *not* scale very well. It usually has much to much boilerplate layers inbetween, so the best you can probably do is to load data from hibernate, copy it into more efficient memory structures, and hope that the hibernate objects are soon garbage collected.
Then perform your analysis entirely independent from hibernate. And once you've done that, feed it back into your hibernate database.

However, before even bothering to think about how to connect it to hibernate, I'd make sure the method actually *works*. Data mining is not a one-click-solution thing. It requires experience and experiments to get anything useful out of your data (otherwise, it wouldn't be data mining, but simple data analysis). Data mining is not one algorithm or application. It is a whole *field* of research that includes statistics, artificial intelligence, machine learning, computer vision, image retrieval and so on. You have a lot to read and try!  **So for now, just forget about Hibernate, and find a method that works for your data**.